# Constraint added programmatically to a xib view not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I have a view(self.printSettingsView) created from xib. I add this view as a subview to another view(self.view). I programmatically add constraints as follows:

```
[self.printSettingView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.printSettingView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.printSettingView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.topBar
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.printSettingView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.printSettingView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];
```

All the other constraints take effect except for height.
What could i be doing wrong here???

Thanks

Comment: Don't use external sites to share code, paste it here. Also, it would be nice to provide some context via screenshots.

Comment: "Not working" is a completely useless expression. You need to say what your code actually did, and what you expected that it would do.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the constraints on your xib file or what you expect to happen vs what is happening (a screenshot would be helpful) it's hard to say.  However I do have one suggestion where maybe the logic isn't correct.

The second constraint is pinning printViewSettings top to the bottom of the topBar, that part makes sense.  The next one however sets the height of printViewSettings to the height of its superview.  This may not jive with what you want because your superview contains your topBar as well and so may be larger than you expect.  What you might actually want is a constraint that pins the bottom of printViewSettings to the bottom of the superview instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys about the incomplete information. The problem in a gist was that i was assigning a constraint to the subview in my main view and whatever be the constant of the constraint the size of the subview remained constant. I found that the issue was the subview in turn had components(subviews) with fixed height constraints. I made them proportional to the height of the parent view and it works now.